# Get a list of all packages loaded in all .Rmd files in a directory

Tags: r, r-markdown, dependency-management

Suppose I have 2 (or any number of) .Rmd files in `~/directory1/`. In each file, I load several R packages using `library(packagename)`. How can I get a character vector containing the names of all unique packages loaded in all of these files?

Comment: doesn't qualify as an outright answer, but you could use the unix tools and do sth like ```cat *.Rmd | grep 'library(' | sort | uniq``` to get a list of all lines including libraries; could still be two or so - but anyways: reading .Rmd as text files and pulling out the library statements is a good 99% way to go.

Comment: another idea: concatenate all *.Rmd with e.g. ```cat ~/directory1/*.Rmd > ~/all_dir1.Rmd```, build the Rmd (although it could take a while) and run ```(.packages())``` in R (either another last Rmd or RStudio, I tried the latter), this gives you all packages that were loaded during computation. As this might take a while, I'd probably go for grepping first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#setwd(~/directory1/)
libs = lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.Rmd$"),
              function(x){
                  d = readLines(x)
                  d = d[grepl("library\\(.*\\)", d)]
                  gsub("library\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", d)
              })
unique(unlist(libs))
```